# ngRepeat:dupes when nothing is duplicated

Tags: angularjs

I am in the process of learning Angular and have run into an error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=skill%20in%20skills%20%7C%20filter%3Asearch&p1=string%3At
```

I am trying to access the skills table in my database and retrieve the rows within. In my JS file I have:

```
function SkillsController($scope, $http) {


$http.get('/skills').success(function(skills) {
    $scope.skills = skills;
});
}
```

in my view:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter skills" ng-model="search">

<div ng-controller="SkillsController" class="skill-contain">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="skill in skills | filter:search">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="skill.has_skill">
        @{{ skill.body }}
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I have tried altering the rows and making sure that nothing inside duplicates, but this does not remove the error.

Comment: try `skill in skills track by $id(skill)`

Comment: No luck with `<li ng-repeat="skill in skills track by $id(skill) | filter:search">`

Comment: Put the input for searching inside the controller?

Comment: @DavidSpence Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a problem but I thought you might have to move your `<input type="text" ng-model="search">` to inside the controller (inside `<div ng-controller... >`) so they're both in scope, but I'm not an expert... Did you try what the url suggests that is within your error? `<li ng-repeat="skill in skills track by $index | filter:search">`

Comment: When I add `track by $index` I get a multitude of checkboxes, but it never shows my single row in the DB

Comment: Ah. [According to this link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3019) the `track by` should be after the filter. Try: `<li ng-repeat="skill in skills | filter:search track by $index">`

Comment: doesn't seem to change anything when placed after the filter :/